# passing long double on x86-64 to a variadic function

Tags: x86-64, variadic-functions, calling-convention, x87

Compiling with gcc on x86-64, I have a function with the signature

```
void * g(void* p, unsigned char a, unsigned char b, ...)
```

and a function call

```
long double zero = 0;
g(NULL, 0, 0, zero);
```

But when `g()` reads the `zero` argument via `va_arg(...,long double)` and compares it `== 0`, the result is `FALSE`!!!

I was experimenting with the assembly output (I don't know the x86-64 calling conventions well), but the output of the function call is

```
fldz
fstpt   -16(%rbp)
pushq   -8(%rbp)
pushq   -16(%rbp)
movl    $0, %edx
movl    $0, %esi
movl    $0, %edi
movl    $0, %eax
call    g
```

and this does not work as I have written above. But when I add an instruction like this

```
...    
fstpt   -16(%rbp)
movw    $0, -6(%rbp) #added instruction
pushq   -8(%rbp)
...
```

it starts to do the right thing. But how can this even have an influence if the `long double` type and what is handled by the FPU, has only 10 bytes. As I understand, the long double argument is passed via [RBP-16],...,[RBP-7], but what is changed among the working and the not working versions is only [RBP-6] and [RBP-5].

Maybe anyone has some ideas? Thank you!

EDIT: This is the C code of g:

```
void * g(void* p, unsigned char a, unsigned char b, ...) {
    va_list list;
    long double x;
    va_start(list, b);
    x = va_arg(list, long double);
    if (x == 0)
        h(q,r);
...
```

and the respective assembler code:

```
g:
pushq   %rbp
movq    %rsp, %rbp
subq    $240, %rsp
movq    %rdi, -232(%rbp)
movq    %rcx, -152(%rbp)
movq    %r8, -144(%rbp)
movq    %r9, -136(%rbp)
testb   %al, %al
je      .L1635
movaps  %xmm0, -128(%rbp)
movaps  %xmm1, -112(%rbp)
movaps  %xmm2, -96(%rbp)
movaps  %xmm3, -80(%rbp)
movaps  %xmm4, -64(%rbp)
movaps  %xmm5, -48(%rbp)
movaps  %xmm6, -32(%rbp)
movaps  %xmm7, -16(%rbp)
.L1635:
movl    %esi, %eax
movb    %al, -236(%rbp)
movl    %edx, %eax
movb    %al, -240(%rbp)
movq    %fs:40, %rax
movq    %rax, -184(%rbp)
xorl    %eax, %eax
movl    $24, -208(%rbp)
movl    $48, -204(%rbp)
leaq    16(%rbp), %rax
movq    %rax, -200(%rbp)
leaq    -176(%rbp), %rax
movq    %rax, -192(%rbp)
movq    -200(%rbp), %rax
addq    $15, %rax
andq    $-16, %rax
leaq    16(%rax), %rdx
movq    %rdx, -200(%rbp)
fldt    (%rax)
fstpt   -224(%rbp)
fldt    -224(%rbp)
fldz
fucomip %st(1), %st
fstp    %st(0)
jp      .L1636
fldt    -224(%rbp)
fldz
fucomip %st(1), %st
fstp    %st(0)
jne     .L1636
leaq    .LC22(%rip), %rsi
leaq    .LC23(%rip), %rdi
call    h
.L1636:
...
```

Comment: It would be a lot simpler to `sub $16, %rsp` ; `fstpt (%rsp)` instead of storing somewhere else and then copying with `push`.  This is what compilers do.  Or for `0.0`, gcc uses `pushq $0` twice https://godbolt.org/g/fYj4oS.  Also, if you prefer Intel syntax (`[rbp-16] .. [rbp-7]`), why not use that instead of AT&T?  But anyway, we can see from clang's and ICC's code-gen that leaving the high 6 bytes of padding unmodified is legal.  Is it possible that a misaligned stack is breaking `g()`?  I think you need to debug `g`, because your caller looks correct.

Comment: I added the code of ```g``` up there. If I compile it on x86-32, there are no problems. However, doesn't ```g``` also look correct? What exactly would happen in case of a misaligned stack? And I really don't get why ```g``` seem to test ```x==0``` twice and why the instructions ```jp``` and ```jne``` would depend on the FPU flags... I agree that the compiler could optimize much here and that I could use Intel syntax. :)

Comment: So is `g` purely compiler-generated?  `jp` tests for unordered (if `x` is NaN), `jne` tests for != 0.0 after it knows the comparison is ordered.  If you compile `g` with optimization enabled, it would be easier to read (less store/reload noise).

Comment: What happens if you write the caller in C?  Does it work then?  If so, maybe single-step through `g` with a debugger (`stepi` in GDB to step by instruction), and see where things go wrong.